# I want to understand more specifically about using Array.prototype.map() in JavaScript with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let progresses = [93,30,55];    
let speeds = [1,30,5];  

function solution(progresses, speeds) {
    progresses.map((v,i) => {
        console.log(speeds[i]);
    })
}
```

Hi! this might be a rather simple question, but I just wanted to make it clear to myself understanding the accessing arrays using the map().

So, I am using Array.prototype.map() to iterate over the progresses array, however when I console.log(speeds[i]), how am I possible to access the speeds array?
So my questions is I am using the map() on progresses array, but why is it also possible to access the speeds array too?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that `map` is not meant to iterate over an Array, for this, use `forEach`, `map` is meant to build a new Array based on the current one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really something particular about how `map()` works, but rather because of closure in JavaScript:

A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function's scope from an inner function.

Comment: You're very welcome! Please remember to mark the answer as correct since it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Every function build in another function have access to all parent function vars. Example:

```js
function test(myVar1, myVar2) {
    return (() => myVar1 + (() => myVar2)())()
}
document.getElementById('test').textContent = test(2, 3)
```

```html
<div id="test">empty</div>
```

To understand more about check the scope of a `var`, `let`, `const`